# Angular material Version

Tags: version, angular-material

is stable the version https://material.angular.io/ ? In the future will be another version that change radically the name of component as the beta8 and beta12?? When will be the last version?

thank you

Comment: Material 2 is still under active development. Current version ( `2.0.0-beta.12` ) is much stable and has alot of fixes. I dont see the names changing too much after that version.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is opinion-based. How do you define `is stable`?

In my opinion, things are still moving fast. Recent examples of breaking changes:

- `MaterialModule` removed altogether.
- `Md*` was replaced with `Mat*` pretty much everywhere.

Here's the best source of knowledge for you: [`@angular/material`'s CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) Just search for "breaking changes".